# creating a Pandas dataframe from a nested dictionary within nested dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I scraped an election site for the state of Pennsylvania in the United States and here's a sample of the resulting nested dictionary from the site's json:

```
some_dict = {'Election': {'Statewide': [{'ADAMS': [{'CandidateName': 'BIDEN, JOSEPH '
                                                     'ROBINETTE JR',
                                    'CountyName': 'ADAMS',
                                    'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                    'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                    },
                                   {'CandidateName': 'TRUMP, DONALD J. ',
                                    'CountyName': 'ADAMS',
                                    'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                    'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                    }],
                         'ALLEGHENY': [{'CandidateName': 'BIDEN, JOSEPH '
                                                         'ROBINETTE JR',
                                        'CountyName': 'ALLEGHENY',
                                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                       },
                                       {'CandidateName': 'TRUMP, DONALD '
                                                         'J. ',
                                        'CountyName': 'ALLEGHENY',
                                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                       }]}]}}
```

I can't figure out how to turn it into a dataframe that would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

some_dict = {'Election': {'Statewide': [{'ADAMS': [{'CandidateName': 'BIDEN, JOSEPH '
                                                     'ROBINETTE JR',
                                    'CountyName': 'ADAMS',
                                    'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                    'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                    },
                                   {'CandidateName': 'TRUMP, DONALD J. ',
                                    'CountyName': 'ADAMS',
                                    'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                    'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                    'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                    }],
                         'ALLEGHENY': [{'CandidateName': 'BIDEN, JOSEPH '
                                                         'ROBINETTE JR',
                                        'CountyName': 'ALLEGHENY',
                                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                       },
                                       {'CandidateName': 'TRUMP, DONALD '
                                                         'J. ',
                                        'CountyName': 'ALLEGHENY',
                                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                                       }]}]}}


df = pd.DataFrame()
for d in some_dict['Election']['Statewide']:
    for k,v in d.items():
        t = pd.DataFrame(v)
        t['CountyName'] = k
        df = pd.concat([df,t])
```

Comment: Amazing. Will accept as answer when that option opens. thx

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can do it in any of the following two methods:

- Method-1: using `pd.read_json()`
- Method-2: using `pd.DataFrame()`
  The `.DataFrame()` method accepts

  - a *`single dict`*

    The keys are the column names and the values are the column-values.
  - a *`list of dicts`*

    Each of the list items is a row of the dataframe, presented as a `dict`: the keys are the column names and values the column values for that specific row.

### Code

Here, we are using the `list of dicts` approach to create the dataframe. First, we **transform the data** into a `list of dicts` using the custom function `prepare_records()` and then apply any of the following two methods.

```py
# prepare records
records = prepare_records(data)

# Method-1: using read_json()
import json
df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(records), orient='records')

# Method-2: using DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=records)
```

**Output**:

```sh
# print(df.to_markdown(index=False))

| CandidateName              | CountyName   |   ElectionDayNoVotes |   ElectionDayVotes |   ElectionDayYesVotes |   ElectionYear |
|:---------------------------|:-------------|---------------------:|-------------------:|----------------------:|---------------:|
| BIDEN, JOSEPH ROBINETTE JR | ADAMS        |                    0 |                  1 |                     0 |           2020 |
| TRUMP, DONALD J.           | ADAMS        |                    0 |                  1 |                     0 |           2020 |
| BIDEN, JOSEPH ROBINETTE JR | ALLEGHENY    |                    0 |                  1 |                     0 |           2020 |
| TRUMP, DONALD J.           | ALLEGHENY    |                    0 |                  1 |                     0 |           2020 |
```

### Custom Function

```py
# custom function
def prepare_records(data):
    records = []
    for county in data['Election']['Statewide'][0].values(): 
        records.extend(county) # same as: records += county
    return records
```

### Dummy Data

```py
data = {
    'Election': 
        {'Statewide': [
            {
                'ADAMS': [
                    {
                        'CandidateName': 'BIDEN, JOSEPH ROBINETTE JR',
                        'CountyName': 'ADAMS',
                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                    },
                    {
                        'CandidateName': 'TRUMP, DONALD J.',
                        'CountyName': 'ADAMS',
                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                    },
                ],
                'ALLEGHENY': [
                    {
                        'CandidateName': 'BIDEN, JOSEPH ROBINETTE JR',
                        'CountyName': 'ALLEGHENY',
                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                    },
                    {
                        'CandidateName': 'TRUMP, DONALD J.',
                        'CountyName': 'ALLEGHENY',
                        'ElectionDayNoVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionDayVotes': '1',
                        'ElectionDayYesVotes': '0',
                        'ElectionYear': '2020'
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

Comment: @SMJune Please take a look at this. Let me know if you have any questions.